# flask session list not working

Tags: python, flask

I have problems updating a list in a flask session.

I have read the docs (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#sessions) and some answers like this one [How to change values in Flask session dictionary using forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713380/how-to-change-values-in-flask-session-dictionary-using-forms) and I use the `session.modified = True` after append, but still getting `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`

Here is my code:

```
@s_cart.route("/cart")
def shopping_cart():
    if "cart" not in session:
        print("There is nothing in your cart.")
        return render_template("cart.html", lista={}, total=0)
    else:
        items = session["cart"]
        cosas = {}
        print(items)
        total_price = 0
        for item in items:
            cassette = aux_methods.get_cassette(item)
            total_price += cassette.price
            if cassette.id in cosas:
                cosas[cassette.id]["qty"] += 1
            else:
                cosas[cassette.id] = {"qty": 1, "name": cassette.title, "price": cassette.price}

    return render_template("cart.html", lista=cosas, total=total_price)


@s_cart.route("/add_to_cart/<_id>")
def add_to_cart(_id):
    if "cart" not in session:
        session["cart"] = []

    session["cart"].append(_id)
    session.modified = True

    return redirect("/cart")
```

and I can't find the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide a full traceback?

Comment: What `aux_methods.get_cassette` do? Do you use SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov http://pastebin.com/aB76eM7Z
Im using mongoengine, aux_methods.get_cassette get the MongoDB document by id

Comment: Is is possible that this bug is related? https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/196

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov I get `<class 'mongoengine.base.datastructures.BaseList'>` after print session list type so, It seems to be that bug :( 
Thank you.